# How does my question need to be "more focused"?

Tags: discussion, question-closure

How does [Why are service or maintenance contracts called 'warranties', when they aren't Legal Warranties?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/562548) "needs to be more focused"? I asked two questions. Do you want me to divide into two separate questions?

[Dr. Franck Dernoncourt observed](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14954/416586)

> As a side note, most non-closed questions on this website do not show any research and the close reason is applied very much arbitrarily.

Comment: There's [a comment that explains](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/562548/why-are-service-or-maintenance-contracts-called-warranties-when-they-arent-l#comment1390871_562548) *'Why don't we use different words for different senses?' is almost always a fruitless question.* Are you asking something other than "Why is *word* used to mean *this definition* when there is this other definition I think is more correct"?

Answer (score 1):

The banners that purport to state the reasons for closing on this site are, more often than not, misleading. This is because (1) the banner displays only one 'reason' from a short menu or standard reasons, which is chosen by some algorithm out of the different reasons that different voters may have picked from the menu, and (2) people often vote on the basis of some gut feeling that the question ought to be closed, and then choose whichever reason on the menu seems close, even if it only very roughly reflects their gut feeling.

This is an unfortunate state of affairs because it is frustrating and alienating to new contributors, who often take the posted reasons at face value. Numerous meta-questions about the reasons for closing make it clear that this is a real problem, but it is unlikely to be remedied any time soon, because revising the menu of the standard reasons for closing is a daunting task.

I suspect that in this case the real reason why the question was closed is that the answer to it is far too obvious (the sense that the word has in everyday contexts is not the same as its techical sense in the law of contracts), but that's only a guess.

Comment: "the sense that the word has in everyday contexts is not the same as its techical sense in the law of contracts" I certainly know this, and we think all do. The question is why?

Comment: @user35209 While that might be an interesting question, it is outside the scope of an SE stack. It doesn't fit well into a Q&A format.